# Calling a PHP string function in an HTML URL. Gives undefined offset 0

Tags: php, html

I have a class for profileImages with a function to display these images. In some parts they work and others I get an undefined offset. I call the function only from an img src URL to display back but get an error.

I might be asking this amateurly but rectifying me would be helpful. 
I am a rookie PHP developer. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

I hope with the code you'll see what I'm trying to achieve.
Here is the code below:

In the images class file.

```
public function DisplayImages($get){
      $src = glob("../../users/$get/avatar/*");
      $path = substr($src[0], 5);
      return $path;
    }
```

In another class file.

```
<img src='{$this->DIR}/".$images->DisplayImages($user_id)."'/>
```

I need the user's ID to be replaced in the URL of src in the DisplayImages function.
If I test the session print it does identify the user's ID in an array as the first key and username as the second key.

I hope this is sufficient information.

I have an "Undefined offset: 0" error. 
What I need is the user_id replaced with the `$get` variable in the function and return the img src URL in the HTML tag and display the image.

Comment: The problem isn't the string function, the problem is that `glob()` isn't finding any matching files, so it returns an empty array.

Comment: Are you sure the `$user_id` variable is set? What do you see if you put `var_dump($user_id);` before this?

Comment: It displays `string(1) "2"` when using `var_dump($user_id);`

Comment: Maybe `../../users` is not the correct path. Try using an absolute path.

Comment: I tried using an absolute path and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You got undefined Index Notice because of "$src[0]" Because glob creates the array with undefined keys for e.g

$x = array("r","p","x");

and if you try to print the print $x[3];

you will get that Notice message because it is an array that does not contain that key.

You can try this->

```
$src = glob("../../users/".$get."/avatar/*");
```

Or Collect Your path of glob, check it really exists.

Comment: All arrays will have indexes - `array("r","p","x")` is the same as `0=> "r", 1=>"p"...`

Comment: yes, but if you Do "print $x[3];" you will get "Notice: Undefined offset: 3", which is not present actually, similar in this question case, $src is not getting value causing the Notice to generate.

Comment: But he's always using index `[0]`.

Comment: That the thing I was to try understand you that, $src was the blank variable, If nothing comes in variable then it shows "Undefined", If the path was right or code have proper permission to access that path, then glob works fine after concatenation of $get. He Must try to access that path directly From the Browser first to  verify.

Comment: How would I grant permission to access that path?

Comment: You should check Is your file accessible through the browser? else you have to give read permission to file based on OS, see the link might help u if you have linux [link](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions)

Comment: It seems my file permissions is not the issue. Still need a solution to this problem though. I fail to return or access the string value, which in this case is simply `2`. This `user_id` is stored as an INT in the DB. Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Comment: let me know one thing are you able to print $user_id above <img> tag?  And also try to print $get at the first line of function. see you got the value or not

Comment: I am able to print the result of the `$user_id` outside the `<img>` tag as well as with the `$get` at function. I can pull both results on either sides. Using both `print_r` and using `var_dump()`

Comment: I tried to access the absolute path of the following `../../users/'.$get.'/avatar/*' ... but it gives me 'Access forbidden' and I have a function that created the user directory using 0755 permissions.

Comment: Then you should check your apache conf file and change Required all denied to Require all granted. see the link helps you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593037/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-localhost)